# Own ads in Android App

Tags: android, admob, ads

I want to add own ads to my android application (by own I mean ads which I set). I've read sugestions on the Stack about Ad House ads in AdMob. I could be ok with it but I can't set my own destination URL (it's permamently linked to google play site).

Have you got any sugestions what's the best solution? Ads will be changed about once a month.

Greetings.:)

Comment: what have you tried?  loading a bitmap from a fixed URL from the app would solve the problem, according to your problem description.

Comment: I haven't try anything according to "think twice code once". So you recommend downloading (for example 5) bitmaps and display them randomly yes? And do some md5 to check if it changed..?

Comment: you don't need md5, timestamp is just about enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you to try [mAdserve](http://madserve.org). It's a self-hosted open source mobile ads server. I've tried it with my apps, and so far it works great.

Comment: ok, I'll try to find out more about it. Can you recomend me some tutorial or site where I can learn it?

Comment: the link is broken